# Hololens: Move Gameobject to random position of spatial map of the room

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapping, spatial, hololens

I'm currently trying to make a gameobject move to a random position on the spatial map of the room I'm using my hololens in. The gameobject should Change it's destination to another random destination and move there after a few seconds. How can I get the x, y and z values of points on the map to use as variables that build a vector3 that I can then set as a destination for the gameobject? I'm using C#.
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whitout any code from your game, it's going to be hard to help you, did you read the "How do i ask good question ?" http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can do a raycast from your gameobject in a random direction and test for a collision with the spatial mesh. Then you have a position (x,y,z) you can move your gameobject towards.